# Send an Email and Associate the Reply to the same record

Tags: email, management

Environment: Salesforce lightning
I am trying to send an email to an external user out of salesforce from a Lead page, I am able to send an email and the user is receiving, For some reason if the external user replies back to the email he/she received, that reply should go and associate to the same record - Lead association is not happening ? I have tried with email to salesforce with bizarre email id and its creating a task but not associating.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know at present replies have to be manually associates w leads.  Only email to case offers the ability to map replies directly to records.  I know ar dreamforce they highlighted automatic association of emails to Salesforce record as something that would be coming w einstein, and there may be apps that do that now, but I don't think there is anything ootb at present.

Comment: Thank you Gorav, so you mean that even after embedding email to salesforce bizarre email address in send and reply emails we need to manually associate that task (Created) to the lead ?

Comment: Email to Salesforce let's you associate outbound emails to Salesforce, when you send them.  This works for replies as well.  Salesforce for outlook would let you associate the inbound response back to Salesforce, manually.  So if I write to you, and copy my email to Salesforce address, the email would be logged in my Salesforce instance.  if you.reply. It would not be logged.  if I reply to your reply and copy my e2sf address it would be logged.  Does that help?